# Menu path with wildcard

Tags: drupal, menu, path, drupal-6

You can't use wildcards in menu paths? A quick summary of my problem (which I've made sure makes sense, so you're not wasting your time): I have a menu which i'm showing on node pages of a certain content-type. My path to a node page would be like...

**events/instal2010**

...where instal2010 would be the name of an event (event is the content-type).

I'm using the Context and Menu Block modules to place a menu in the sidebar on that page...

- Event (the default active item)
- Programme
- Visitor info
- Book tickets

... where the path for Programme would be

**events/instal2010/programme**

So for this to work for many different events, those menu items need a wildcard in their path, e.g.

**events/*/programme**

Perhaps it's time to ditch menus and just use a block with php to determine what page we're on from the URL.

Any advice from experienced hands would be awsome, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create menu items with wildcards from the administrative interface of Drupal, but you **can** create menu items with wildcards in a module.  I would recommend creating a custom module that uses [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to create the menu items.  An example implementation would look something like:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['events/%/programme'] = array(
    'title' => 'Programme',
    'description' => 'Loads a program page',
    'page callback' => 'YOUR CUSTOM FUNCTION NAME', // Custom function used to perform any actions, display the page, etc
    'page arguments' => array(1),  // Passes wildcard (%) to your page callback function
    'access callback' => TRUE, // Change if you want to control access
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, // Creates a link in the menu
    'menu_name' => 'primary-links' // Adds the link to your primary links menu, change if needed
  );

  return $items;
}
```

In `$items['events/%/programme'] = array(`, the `%` is the wildcard and it will be passed to your page callback function.  It may be helpful to read more about [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) and the [Anatomy of hook_menu](http://drupal.org/node/300997) may also help as well.